# How to read excel table with one column?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have a table in Excel with one column that I want to read into the list:
[image: table]

At first I tried it like this:

```py
>>> df = pandas.read_excel('emails.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
>>> df
OrderedDict([('Sheet1',                Chadisayed@gmx.com
0                wonderct@mail.ru
1                  fcl@fcl-bd.com
2    galina@dorax-investments.com
>>> for k, v in df.items():
...     print(type(v), v)
...
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>                Chadisayed@gmx.com
0                wonderct@mail.ru
1                  fcl@fcl-bd.com
2    galina@dorax-investments.com
>>> df = df.items()[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'odict_items' object is not subscriptable
```

I tried it differently:

```py
>>> df = pandas.read_excel('emails.xlsx', index_col=0)
>>> df
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [wonderct@mail.ru, fcl@fcl-bd.com, galina@dorax-investments.com]

[419 rows x 0 columns]
>>> foo = []
>>> for i in df.index:
...     foo.append(i)
...
>>> foo
['wonderct@mail.ru', 'fcl@fcl-bd.com', 'galina@dorax-investments.com']
```

It almost worked, but the first element is missing. What else can I do? Is there really no way to read the Excel file simply line by line?

Comment: add 'header=None" in `pandas.read_excel('emails.xlsx', sheet_name=None)`, so, something like `pandas.read_excel('emails.xlsx', sheet_name=None,header=None)`

Comment: @moys nothing changed. Now this is an empty DataFrame in OrderedDict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df=pd.read_excel('temp.xlsx', header=None)
target_list=list(df[0].values)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'A'

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
target_list = pandas.read_excel('emails.xlsx', index_col=None, names=['A'])['A'].tolist()
```